# How to use Hero framework?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm learning to use this popular animation framework on Github: https://github.com/lkzhao/Hero

I built a test project, like this:

[image]

This is my `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var animationObject: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        isHeroEnabled = true
        animationObject.heroModifiers = [.fade, .translate(x:0, y:-250), .rotate(x:-1.6), .scale(1.5)]
    }
}
```

When I ran the project, the view doesn't move. I have no idea how to make it work from the wiki page of `Hero`, so is there somebody who can give me a hint?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hero is the library for `ViewController` transition, so you needs at least two `ViewController` to see transition effect.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to also set hero enabled on a navigation controller if you use one.

Answer (score 0):

You are running this demo into iphone 7 plus simulator. Inn library there is one note that **Hero does not work on iPhone 7 (Plus) Simulators due to an Apple bug. Please use other simulators or a real device when working with Hero.**

So please try to run it on different simulators

Comment: Now I run it with iPhone 6s simulator, it still doesn't animate

Comment: What do you want to do like in animation type ?

Comment: Ok, I will try and let you know why it's not working

Comment: @BrightFuture will you send me demo, I got too much error in library

Comment: OK, how do I send you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135743/discussion-between-jecky-modi-and-bright-future).